# Limit clients that can connect to server

Tags: c

I made a TCP client-server program in C under Linux using select(). I was wondering how can I limit the number of clients that connect to the server. That is if I can before they get accept()-ed.

Here is the code, sorry of the language of comments. I still didn't get where to put that if.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>

/* portul folosit */

#define PORT 2728

extern int errno;       /* eroarea returnata de unele apeluri */

/* functie de convertire a adresei IP a clientului in sir de caractere */
char * conv_addr (struct sockaddr_in address)
{
    static char str[25];
    char port[7];

    /* adresa IP a clientului */
    strcpy (str, inet_ntoa (address.sin_addr)); 
    /* portul utilizat de client */
    bzero (port, 7);
    sprintf (port, ":%d", ntohs (address.sin_port));    
    strcat (str, port);
    return (str);
}
int v[4]; //vector cu 5 tipuri de mancare
/* programul */
int main ()
{ int nrclienti=0; v[0]=0; v[1]=0; v[2]=0; v[3]=0; v[4]=0;
    int inchid=1;
    int x,max,pmax;max=v[0];pmax=0;int pref;
    struct sockaddr_in server;  /* structurile pentru server si clienti */
    struct sockaddr_in from;
    fd_set readfds;     /* multimea descriptorilor de citire */
    fd_set actfds;      /* multimea descriptorilor activi */
    struct timeval tv;      /* structura de timp pentru select() */
    int sd, client;     /* descriptori de socket */
    int optval=1;           /* optiune folosita pentru setsockopt()*/ 
    int fd;         /* descriptor folosit pentru 
                parcurgerea listelor de descriptori */
    int nfds;           /* numarul maxim de descriptori */
    int len;            /* lungimea structurii sockaddr_in */

    /* creare socket */
    if ((sd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror ("[server] Eroare la socket().\n");
        return errno;
    }

    /*setam pentru socket optiunea SO_REUSEADDR */ 
    setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,&optval,sizeof(optval));

    /* pregatim structurile de date */
    bzero (&server, sizeof (server));

    /* umplem structura folosita de server */
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port = htons (PORT);

    /* atasam socketul */
    if (bind (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof (struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror ("[server] Eroare la bind().\n");
        return errno;
    }

    /* punem serverul sa asculte daca vin clienti sa se conecteze */
    if (listen (sd, 5) == -1)
    {
        perror ("[server] Eroare la listen().\n");
        return errno;
    }

    /* completam multimea de descriptori de citire */
    FD_ZERO (&actfds);      /* initial, multimea este vida */
    FD_SET (sd, &actfds);       /* includem in multime socketul creat */

    tv.tv_sec = 1;      /* se va astepta un timp de 1 sec. */
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    /* valoarea maxima a descriptorilor folositi */
    nfds = sd;

    printf ("[server] Asteptam la portul %d...\n", PORT);
    fflush (stdout);

    /* servim in mod concurent clientii... */

    while (inchid)
    {   /* ajustam multimea descriptorilor activi (efectiv utilizati) */
        bcopy ((char *) &actfds, (char *) &readfds, sizeof (readfds));

        /* apelul select() */
        if (select (nfds+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv) < 0)
        {
            perror ("[server] Eroare la select().\n");
            return errno;
        }
        /* vedem daca e pregatit socketul pentru a-i accepta pe clienti */
        if (FD_ISSET (sd, &readfds))
        {
            /* pregatirea structurii client */
            len = sizeof (from);
            bzero (&from, sizeof (from));

            /* a venit un client, acceptam conexiunea */
            client = accept (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &from, &len);


            /* eroare la acceptarea conexiunii de la un client */
            if (client < 0)
            {
                perror ("[server] Eroare la accept().\n");
                continue;
            }
            if (nfds < client) /* ajusteaza valoarea maximului */
            nfds = client;

            printf("[server] S-a conectat clientul cu descriptorul %d, de la adresa %s.\n",client, conv_addr (from));

            /* includem in lista de descriptori activi si acest socket */
            FD_SET (client, &actfds); 


            fflush (stdout);
        }
        /* vedem daca e pregatit vreun socket client pentru a trimite raspunsul */
        for (fd = 0; fd <= nfds; fd++)  /* parcurgem multimea de descriptori */
        {
            /* este un socket de citire pregatit? */
            if (fd != sd && FD_ISSET (fd, &readfds))
            {   //func

                char buffer[100];       /* mesajul */
                int bytes;          /* numarul de octeti cititi/scrisi */
                char msg[100];      //mesajul primit de la client 
                char msgrasp[100];        //mesaj de raspuns pentru client
                int replies=0;
                do
                {
                    //citim mesajul de la client
                    bytes = read (fd, msg, sizeof (buffer));
                    if (bytes < 0)
                    {
                        perror ("Eroare la read() de la client.\n");
                        return 0;
                    }
                    printf ("[server]Clientul cu descriptorul %d a ales mancarea %s\n",fd, msg);

                    int poz; //comanda alease introdusa in vectorul de comenzi
                    poz = msg[0] - '0';
                    v[poz-1]++;

                    //decidem felul preferat din meniu
                    printf("[server]");
                    for(x=0;x<=4;x++)
                    if (max<v[x]) {max=v[x];pmax=x;} 
                    pref=pmax+1;
                    for(x=0;x<=4;x++) printf("%d|",v[x]);
                    printf(" Val max e %d\n",pref);

                    /*pregatim mesajul de raspuns */
                    bzero(msgrasp,100);
                    sprintf(msgrasp, "%d", pref);

                    //daca clientului corespunde cu mancarea favorita, trimitem raspunsul
                    if (msg[0]==msgrasp[0]) sprintf(msgrasp, "%d", 1);
                    else sprintf(msgrasp, "%d", 0);

                    printf("[server]Trimitem %s clientului %d\n",msgrasp,fd);

                    if (bytes && write (fd, msgrasp, bytes) < 0)
                    {
                        perror ("[server] Eroare la write() catre client.\n");
                        return 0;
                    }
                    //func
                    replies++;
                }while((msgrasp[0]!=49)&&(replies<3));

                printf ("[server] S-a deconectat clientul cu descriptorul %d.\n\n",fd);
                fflush (stdout);
                close (fd);     /* inchidem conexiunea cu clientul */
                FD_CLR (fd, &actfds);/* scoatem si din multime */


            }
        }           /* for */
    }               /* while */
    close(sd);}             /* main */
```

Comment: Can you stop `listen()`ing after there have been enough `accept()`s? This is a simple way but a tcp client may not end a connection for a long time, and it is not the server's responsibility to do so. - you can limit the number of queued (pending) connections too, using `listen`'s second argument.

Comment: Using listen's backlog doesn't work for me. I am going to try the 1st thing.

Comment: The backlog only determines how many connections are *waiting* to be accepted, not how many are currently accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you are running a non-threaded non-forking application using `select()`. If not, then the you will need to modify this a little but not much.

Prior to `select()`, you will be adding each of your fd's corresponding to an open session to your `fd_set` using `FD_SET`; you can count these whilst you loop through. You will also add your listener fd. Simply omit this second step if the number of open connections is at its maximum.

Note that open connections may still be accepted later - see how `backlog` works on `listen()`.

Comment: for (fd = 0; fd <= nfds; fd++) //descriptors if (fd != sd && FD_ISSET (fd, &readfds)) //is a reading socket ready?....Yes here it is. So what should I do?

Comment: If it's a master socket, just ignore it. Or simply don't include master socket into `readfds` set.

Comment: You can't just ignore it, or you will busy wait when there is a pending connection (i.e. `select` will return you have something to do, but then you will do nothing, go back into `select` etc). The correct action is to not add it to the `readfds` prior to the `select`, in which case you will never have `FD_ISSET` return true for it later.

Comment: Then how should I do it?

Comment: As I just said. *Prior* to the `select()` you will be adding each of your FDs to `readfds` using `FD_SET`. Add all the fds relating to connections, but only add the fd for your listen socket if you actually want to accept other connections (i.e. if you have fewer than the limit). It's just one `if` statement!

Comment: One more thing, what if I want to tell my client that he's not accepted? Since I can't send him a message without actually accepting him...

Comment: You can't communicate on an inbound connection without accepting it. However, you can accept it, write "go away I'm busy" (either use your FD loop or don't check for an error), then close the connection straight away. Obviously in this case you *will* always want to add the listenfd in.

Comment: That's what I thought, too. Thought there was another way. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, I still have problems. I think I may do something wrong. I pasted my original code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't need a client you may not accept() him :) Thus you may limit the number of clients currently being processed. Just ignore events on your master socket and you've done.
Also you can limit the size of the queue for clients not been accepted yet using TCP backlog, notice the second parameter of `listen()`

But typically it's not quite, ehmm, polite. Maybe you should re-think your entire task and decide how to handle more clients simultaneously.

Comment: The server uses select so it can handle multiple clients at the same time. But it simulates a restaurant, so I need limited 'tables'.